# How to add Google Analytics code to Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, google-analytics, drupal-theming

I want to add my Google Analytics code to my Drupal site without using the module. I read threads related to this but I can't make it on my website. I want to put my code inside the `<head></head>` tag. Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'example.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

Comment: any particular reason why do you want to do that without using the module?

Comment: I am curious too. I can't see a reason not to use the module yet there are reason good reasons to use a module (e.g. A module can update the embedded script if there is any change in Google analytics script)

Comment: If you want to be verified as an owner of a site in some other Google services (eg. Search Console), you need to have Google Analytics code inside `head` tag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open the folder `modules/system` in your Drupal install, then copy `html.tpl.php` file to your theme's directory. Add the code you like to the file and save.

Don't forget to clear the cache.

Comment: The file will be copied just inside `MYTHEME/` directory? Or inside `MYTHEME/Templates`? Cause I found my `page.tpl.php` right there.

Comment: Anywhere is fine. It's up to you :)

Comment: I can see now the script from the source. How would I know that my javascript works? Thasnk!

Comment: Open your website from different browsers, then open your Google Analytics account and see the data there. It should record your visits.

Answer (score 7):

On a Drupal site, you want to insert additional javascript using the drupal_add_js function inside the THEME_preprocess_html function in the template.php file. Doing so allows you to properly cache your site. Specifically, this is how it would look:

```
<?php
    function THEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {

      $ga  = "var _gaq = _gaq || [];\n";
      $ga .= "_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X']);\n";
      $ga .= "_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'example.com']);\n";
      $ga .= "_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);\n";
      $ga .= "(function() {\n";
      $ga .= "  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;\n";
      $ga .= "  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';\n";
      $ga .= "  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);\n";
      $ga .= "})();\n";

      drupal_add_js($ga, array('type' => 'inline', 'scope' => 'header'));
    }
?>
```

Be sure to replace the UA ID and website name with your own. Also, be sure to rename THEME to your theme and clear the cache when complete.

Comment: +1. But why getting the code from `html.tpl.php` is not so good?

Comment: google analytics give a javascript code, maybe this code (javascript) will not working.